# How to align text to top of flex container without added margins?

Tags: css

It seems a regular div leaves some empty default space above/below a line of text. This becomes a problem on different engines (ios VS android). **How to make sure the space marked in blue has no margin?**

Code: https://codepen.io/manuWebFE/pen/bGYYbYB

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background: red;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
  <div class="content">
    Some text
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Your second div was closed as `</die>` which I adjusted in the edits.

Comment: Are you trying to say you want the text in the top left on top of the image? In that case add `position: absolute;` on to `content`. You can also adjust the `line-height` so it appears there is no space between text and top of container.

Comment: Have you tried using `line-height`?

Comment: That space is reserved for `ÂÊ` and the same character

Comment: @TemaniAfif interesting, I had no idea but makes logical sense.

Comment: line-height is an interesting approach. but how do you make it work when there are multiple lines? 
                .content:first-line {
                    line-height: X; // slightly smaller than the text
                }
might help but the second row is glued.

Comment: line-height will help you

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the line-height property like this `line-height: 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Try using negative margins, like this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background: red;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.content {
  margin-top: -7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
  <div class="content">
    Some text
    </div>
  </div>
```

Maybe it changes according to the resolutions...

Comment: "without added margins"